# Pytrend get_daily_data column meaning

Tags: python, pandas, google-trends

I'm using pytrend to do some basic data analysis. Here's my code

```
from pytrends import dailydata
df = dailydata.get_daily_data('blockchain', 2020, 4, 2020, 5, geo = '')
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

I'm struggling to understand the meaning of each column. Can anyone explain them?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same doubt and found the correct answer at this website:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/master/pytrends/dailydata.py

https://medium.com/@yanweiliu/getting-the-google-trends-data-with-python-67b335e7d1cf

```
Returns:
    complete (pd.DataFrame): Contains 4 columns.
        The column named after the word argument contains the daily search
        volume already scaled and comparable through time.
        The column f'{word}_unscaled' is the original daily data fetched
        month by month, and it is not comparable across different months
        (but is comparable within a month).
        The column f'{word}_monthly' contains the original monthly data
        fetched at once. The values in this column have been backfilled
        so that there are no NaN present.
        The column 'scale' contains the scale used to obtain the scaled
        daily data.
```